# On judgement day, will your sins be exposed and judged in front of everyone?

Tags: allah, sin, judgements, day-of-judgement

On judgement day, when Allah judges you, is it just between you and Him, or will He expose and judge your sins in front of everyone?

Comment: For believers there may be a vail, I'll do research and find out!

Answer (score -1):

**It could be surveyed from two different angles. Firstly on judgment day, one group of people will be judged in front of other people. Secondly the other group will be covered.**

Briefly speaking, it depends upon the person who would be judged by Allah and in fact it depends upon his/her deeds. For instance a bad person who has done plenty of Haram acts, probably Allah will judge him in front of other people (as a negative effect of his negative deeds)

The other group of people who are considered as good people, hence Allah will judge them in front of other people. (if Allah wants) (as a face-saving).
Totally, we can not give an specific response, since it could be related to the deeds of people, and if will Allah intends to save their face or not.

Comment: plz provide references for your answer.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference for your answer?

Answer (score -1):

On the Day of Judgment, every individual's deeds and actions will be brought forth and judged by Allah, the ultimate judge of all affairs. All good deeds will be rewarded, and all bad deeds will be punished, based on the person's intention and sincerity.

The Quran states, "And every small and great [deed] is recorded" (surah Al-Qamar, verse 53).

However, the specific manner in which the judgment will take place is known only to Allah. Muslims believe that Allah is just and merciful, and His judgment will be fair and based on the person's true intentions and actions. Some Islamic scholars believe that the sins of believers will be kept private and not exposed publicly, while others believe that the sins will be exposed and judged publicly. However, the specifics of how this will be done are not specified in Islamic teachings.

It is important for Muslims to focus on doing good deeds and repenting for their sins in this life, in order to attain Allah's forgiveness and mercy on the Day of Judgment.